# How to use a variable in a href link?

Tags: variables

How can I use a variable in the follow href element:

Example, instead of https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/ I like to use a variable. But I do not know how to get it in Magento.

Kindly Simon

Comment: Is that url your store url?

Comment: Cannot understand your point?

Comment: We have a multistore wise set up. And in the navigation menu i have some images, I like to link to some category pages.

So we have 4 different "stores"

- https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active/
- https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/
- https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/
- https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/work/

In each we have subcategories like brands/asics etc

Comment: Instead of writing "hardcoded" https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active/

I like to write and use a variable for it... But I do not know if a variable given from Magento exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has handy helpers so that you don't need to hard code the links. You can use the following to go to  mag.outdoorequipped.com/active in a phtml file:

`Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB) . '/active'`

or in a cms block:

`{{store url="/active"}}`

In phtml files

1. Get Base Url : `Mage::getBaseUrl();`
2. Get Skin Url : `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);`
3. Get Media Url : `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);`
4. Get Js Url : `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);`
5. Get Store Url : `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);`
6. Get Current Url `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();`

In cms pages or static blocks

1. Get Base Url : `{{store url=""}}`
2. Get Skin Url : `{{skin url='images/imagename.jpg'}}`
3. Get Media Url : `{{media url='/imagename.jpg'}}`
4. Get Store Url : `{{store url='mypage.html'}}`

Comment: Okay, I see, so I have my html code at the moment under categories, then  "Menu". And there I have my html code...

I can put there instead html code a static block?

Comment: correct so inside your static block add `{{store url="/active"}}` which should give you the correct url

Comment: So if I like to have in my href="https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active/brands/asics.html"

I need to do in the static block:

href="{{store url="/active"}}/brands/asics.html" ?

Comment: then it would need to be {{store url="/active/brands/asics"}} magento will work out the rest but just double check first.

Comment: okay, I see, will test it later. Where I need it is here:

https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/active

And then in the navigation menu I have under "Brands" 6 images with links.

Comment: @SimonVetterli It should work there.

Answer (score 1):

I did as followed and it works for me nice:

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/clarks.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/clarks.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/dr-martens.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/drmartens.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/kenneth-cole.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/kennethcole.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/royal-robbins.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/royalrobbins.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/sebago.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/sebago.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
<div class="col-sm-2"><a href="{{store direct_url="brands/gh-bass.html"}}"><img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/menulogo/fashion/ghbass.jpg"}}" /></a></div>
```